Getting error while compiling 'DocumentFormat::OpenXml::UInt32Value' you must reference the assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Framework'
While compiling the openxml module using DocumentFormat.OpenXml version 3.0.2 ,I am getting the following error
error C3465: to use type 'DocumentFormat::OpenXml::UInt32Value' you must reference the assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Framework'
This was compiling successfully using open xml 2.19.
Could you please help how to solve this error

did you try to do what the error said?

Yes ..i tried to add,but it's recognising it as a namespace and throwing different kinds of error .On the otherside I have seen in release notes that framework is newly introduced but it won't affect compilation..Not sure if I need to add anything else

I get rid of this issue by adding DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Framework.dll to my compilation path.
